# How do I get pdf page thumbnails to display in QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uidocumentinteraction, qlpreviewcontroller

In iOS 6, I noticed that when I preview a PDF document using the UIDocumentInteractionController, it displays nice looking page thumbnails down the right side of the screen.  However, if I display the same PDF using the QLPreviewController, those thumbnails do not appear.

How can I get the QLPreviewController to display thumbnails of PDF pages in the same way that the UIDocumentInteractionController does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thumbnails appear for me when I use QLPreviewController using

```
[self presentViewController:previewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Have you tried presenting the controller modally?

Comment: I am using the QLPreviewController in a non-modal manner, and they are not displaying.  I'm guessing they only display when presented modally.  I'll go ahead and accept your answer as a result.

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that they display when presented modally. I'm not sure where I read it, but I think it was in Apple documentation somewhere. OK. I take that back. I think I just asked that because it's the way I presented it.

Comment: It is working in iPad but thumbnails are not displaying in iPhone.